# how to change font size on html list using css

Tags: html, css

O. Guys.
i got an apex app and i am using Jquery Mobile Theme, but basically i got some list items i need to display on my screen, but my screen is a handheld, which has small screen size, so when i display the list item the size is too big, i will like to reduce font size.
in my apex html page i got a **"CSS Inline"** section and actually got some code like this one below in which i reduced the font size of text and number fields, but i don’t know how to reduce font size of list item, i guess is easy but actually i am new on html and css stuff..

thanks in advance.

```
input[type="text"] {font-size:8px}
input[type="number"] {font-size:8px}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can apply the font size for list item as below in css file

```
ul li{
 font-size:8px;
}
```

In inline css:

```
<ul >
<li style="font-size:50px";>item1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10):

Give your UL class a name:

```
<ul class="bigFont">
```

Add your `<li>` items

```
<li>Hello world</li>
<li>Hello world1</li>
</ul>
```

add style

```
.bigFont li{
font-size:8px;
}
```

Comment: [The top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21059817/1705829) is a bit older and has the same content, so I would favour to delete your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If is a list, you can do

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400){
   ul li {
   font-size: .8em;
   }
}
```

- nested in media query for only apply in small screen
- if you have a link nested in li, select tag a or put class name
- is a good practice use unit relative